# how to save the content of an input box on electron locally

Tags: java, html, electron, save, local

I would like the contents of what I put in here to save after I click a save button, how would I go about that? Anything I have tried finding online doesn't answer my question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXwhD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Search for a CRUD application, there're several good tutorials on CRUD apps, this is my favorite:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D67Liy5C86s

And please, node.js/electronjs and javascript are languages totally different from java.